# How do I know if a certain website uses json / xml?

Tags: xml, json, jsonp

I'm aware this is a beginner question, but I couldn't find anything so I came here.

I want to use jQuery jsonp and for that I understood the website I want to extract data from should use json / xml, so far am I right?

It's probably as simple as going to developer tools in Chrome and look for json / xml files, but I just wanna be sure. how do I know for sure if a certain website uses json / xml? there should be .json / .xml files somewhere?

Comment: If you're making a JSONP call then the server you are calling must support it. There need not be any JSON or XML files - they could be generated on-the-fly. The only way to know what is offered is by reading the documentation for the service the site is offering.

Comment: @HoboSapiens is right. What website are you looking to extract data from?

Comment: local shopping websites, one is php and the other one is aspx. I searched for an api but couldn't find any. if I want to extract some data, is jsonp is my best choice before screen scraping / using qa tools like junit and casperjs?